# how to set the password to excel sheet using java

Tags: java, excel, hssfworkbook

Iam trying to set the password using Hssf workbook and Biff8EncryptionKey.But iam not getting any response.

```
 HSSFWorkbook writeWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
       Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("pass");
       NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File("C:\\Users\\Visaws\\Desktop\\test4.xls"), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code

```
private boolean importTables(InputStream stream, String fileName) throws Exception {
Workbook workbook;
if (fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".xls")) {
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(decryptKey)) {
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword("1234567");
}
workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);
} else {
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported file format!");
}
stream.close();
int sheetNumber = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
for (int i = 0; i < sheetNumber; i++) {
createTable(workbook.getSheetAt(i));
}
database.close();
return true;
}
```